# Android application with multi language support

Tags: android, menu

I have to create application with 3 languages, 
it's good and working fine with everything but with auto-load language i have problems.
i have used this method http://snowpard-android.blogspot.co.uk/2013/03/programmatically-change-language-in.html
but it said noting about menu.
this is what i did with menus in updateTexts() function.

```
/*for menus*/     
MenuItem gpscrp = menu.findItem(R.id.gpscrp);
gpscrp.setTitle(R.string.m_gcp);
/*for other text on the app */
a_te= getString(R.string.a_te);
```

but my problem is when i change language in `OnCreate function` like (`changeLang("en")`)
i get error on this line, `updateTexts();` 
i have no idea what the problem is?
but it works find when i use `changeLang("en")` after loading the application. i mean when i call it from other function like press button.

note: it works find with texts on the application, the problem is the menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`onCreate(...)` is called before `onCreateOptionsMenu(...)` therefore your global variable `menu` is null and `MenuItem gpscrp = menu.findItem(R.id.gpscrp);` will throw a NullPointerException.

it should be enough to check first if menu is null or not.

Comment: thank you, i have added an exception on updateTexts(), but how can i load values on load up, all the strings are empty. and the app will not work.

Comment: i have added loadLocale() function in onCreateOptionsMenu , it's working fine, it will be ok right ?

Comment: yes, just set the text in onCreateOptionsMenu, if you don't plan to change the language after the activity is loaded up

Comment: i am changing the locale in OnCreate and update the text in onCreateOptionsMenu, it works fine, thank you.